# what is Nava Shraddha, Nagna Srardham , Vrishotsarga, Ekoddishta, Sapthaham, Maasika

Tags: rituals, death, shraddha

In relation to rituals after death, I am looking for better clarity on the following topics:-

1. Nagna Srardham
2. Nava Shraddha
3. Vrishotsarga
4. Ekoddishta
5. Saptaha
6. Maasika: This is last chapter in the karma karriya. This is something about offering food for the next 11 months.

Comment: What’s nagna srardham? Is the spelling somewhat wonky or that’s how it is?

Comment: yes this is one procedure after fire the body. [Nagna Shraddham] , you can google u can see few links as well

Comment: Couldn’t find anything :). Don’t know about Nava Shraddha, Nagna. Based on my knowledge I’ll tell you the rest. Person dies. Then you are ideally supposed to do shraddha for one week(saptahik), 15 days (pakshika), tri pakshika (1.5 months), and then monthly (maasik) till the 11.5th month when the annual one is done. Your maasika and saptaha get covered here. Ekoddishta is a shraddha specifically done for an individual on the death tithi (first time is after 12 months) thereafter every year, specific to that individual only. You don’t call other ancestors. Vrishotsarga means leaving a bull.

Comment: On the 11th day some mantras for devatas are chanted, a bull is worshipped and left either in a gaushala or open on the road and one is supposed to feed him food for one year. As per Garuda purana it’s supposed to give a lot of punya (merit) for the ancestor. Vrisha = bull, utsarga means leaving.

Comment: My advice is to consult a pandith familiar with such matters and silence in social media nudge,nudge,wink,wink.

Comment: Thanks @GopalAnantharaman i am doing research ,  what stories are people holding for these topics, Looking good articles, so i can create the document and share with current and next generation.

Comment: every one know, one common statement, when person die they move from boologam, but it is mandatory, people should know, how really process working. why people following above mentioned topics.

Comment: These are all support systems which survive on the sound  of utterances for directing the soul over a year to its real destination. Who does those completely these times? In the ‘soul’ sukshma sarira there is only so much you could do to move. Rest are lost